# C++ program exited with code 0 error

Tags: c++

I'm doing c++ at my job for the first time in years and am trying to track down a problem. I wrote code that goes out and enumerates the processes running on a machine and returns performance metrics. My problem is that some sort of unhandled error occurs and in the debug window I get a message saying the program has exited with code 0. Here is the code in the main function

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        while(nRun == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteHeartBeat();
                DoProcessLoop(dwTotalRAM, nCheckPause, oPMeter, cFileName, oProcess, oCPUUsage, nProcCount, ddsCaps2, lpDD);
                CopyPerfFileToDest(cFileName);
                nRun = 1;
                tEnd = time(NULL);
            }catch(...){
                AddToLog("Error in Main Function");
            }
        }

    AddToLog("App Stopped");
    return 0;
    }
```

The program runs for a long time but after a while it just comes back saying it exited with code 0 but that "App Stopped" line is never printed into the log.  Does anyone know what kind of error I could have or what issue could be occuring?  Is that try catch block sufficient enough to catch any error that could occur or is there something else I could do. Any help you could offer would be really appreciated.

EDIT: The log file should get 3 entries from here if it exits correctly. They are "Doing Process Loop" for the the "DoProcessLoop" Function, "Copying File" for the "CopyPerfFileToDest" function and the "App Stopped" if it stops correctly. When I make it stop correctly myself I get all 3 lines, when it is stopping incorrectly I only get "Doing Process Loop" in the log and then it exits with code 0. The error must be in there. I was curious if there is a generic error trap I can do to catch any all errors.

Comment: this code doesn't really show what could go wrong, there's three functions in there, where an error could occur, but we can't see them.

Comment: if it exits with error code 0, it means that it exited normally, fyi

Comment: Are you sure AddToLog writes to the log with flushing? Otherwise you could be exiting at the bottom without seeing the log line.

Comment: The log file should get 3 entries from here if it exits correctly.  They are "Doing Process Loop" for the the "DoProcessLoop" Function, "Copying File" for the "CopyPerfFileToDest" function and the "App Stopped" if it stops correctly.  When I make it stop correctly myself I get all 3 lines, when it is stopping incorrectly I only get  "Doing Process Loop" in the log and then it exits with code 0.  The error must be in there.  I was curious if there is a generic error trap I can do to catch any all errors.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if one of functions called from _tmain called exit(0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx

Comment: return 0 from main is the same as exit(0);  main is effectively exit(main(args));

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes files are not flushed right so if the AddToLog function defers writing to a file right before exit then it might not write out the value. You can debug the program to see if something strange is happening, or add a variable like status and set it in your catch function then return it at the end, so you know based on the value if there was an error.

Comment: When I exit the program correctly myself then I do get all the proper lines in the log that I need.  When the program exits itself I get 1 of the 3 lines I need.  The "CopyPerfFileToDest" function should also write to the log inside it but it never does when it exits unexpectedly

Comment: Yeah, that's the cache flush problem, if the program dies unexpectedly then the logger has unwritten statements. Sometimes I just write to stderr to get around the caching on the loggers. The manpages for C library functions can be surprisingly informative about what you can do with them. For example the open manpage notes that the operation is atomic so I can be used for locks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return of addtolog with a boolean and surrounding add to log with:

```
boolean logged=false;
while(!logged){
  logged = AddToLog("App Stopped");
}
```

This should prevent the program from exiting until "App Stopped" is written, which may be the problem.